# angular observable does not load service after subject.next

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an input text that searches in my database and returns a list to fill in my ng-for. If empty, it shows all records. Through a modal I insert a new record and wanted to update my list, but when sending empty the observable does not fire.

**Component**

```
private exameIdSubject = new Subject<string>();
 anexoExames$ = this.exameIdSubject.pipe(
   startWith(''),
   liveSearch(search => this.apiExames.getAnexoExame(search))    
);


searchExame(search: string) {                   
  this.exameIdSubject.next(search);        
}


onSubmit(){             
  if(this.exameForm.valid){       
     this.apiExames.addAnexoExame(this.exameForm.value)
     .subscribe((exame:any)=>{
        this.exameForm.reset();          
        this.searchExame('')            
     })          
  }        
 }
```

The modal saves on **onSubmit** and emit empty to update the list, as the value has already been used it does nothing.

Operator LiveSearch https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/a-live-search-example-angular-and-react-solutions-bd42a4d5dd7e

**Update**

**Html**

```
<div class="search-results mb-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" (input)="searchExame($event.target.value)" placeholder="Busca...">       
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="anexoExames$ | async as vanexos; else indicator">
  ...
  <tr *ngFor="let anexo of vanexos; let i=index">
   ...
```

Comment: Where is `anexoExames$` subscribed to?

Comment: Try it with: `private exameIdSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>();`

Comment: unsuccessfully, when the page loads, the empty value is passed, which returns all values, but when I fire empty again by the modal button it realizes that it is the same "empty" value and does not send the request to the service